# Creating "came-from" navigation - PHP

Tags: php, navigation

I was wondering, how is it possible to get example the last X number of pages a user came from on my site?

I am creating a navigation, so the user easily can see the X number of previuos pages he visited **on my site only**.

I just don't know how to do this. Is there any function in PHP to obtain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pages of your site or pages from the sites user was *before* entered yours?

Comment: Edited the question. On my site only.

Comment: Whats wrong with the back button? All browser already support a list in the back button. Try not to implement a browser inside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the last X pages on your site only, and that you know how to use sessions and arrays.

In this case you could initialize a session for the user, then every time the user visits a page, append the URL or some identified of that page to the array. If there's more than X pages in the array, additionally remove the first one.

Then you could just get the contents of the array, parse them into a bunch of links and show them on your site.

In case you meant the pages before entering your site, you can only get the latest one via the referer header. Some browsers might be configured to not send the referer header, however, so there really isn't a way of accomplishing this properly.

Comment: Could you provide an example of this for me?

Comment: Narf did that above. He just left out the part about removing the first one if there's more than X but I really can't figure out how to get the first element, myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
/*
   Put here any logic that could result in a redirect, to avoid useless records
   ...
*/

$_SESSION['history'][] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

`$_SESSION['history']` is now an indexed array with all of the user's history on your website.